# Setting state to a zero-filled array with Immer in react-toolkit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit, immer.js

I was following the [TS usage docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript) and now I'm trying to clear an array using Redux Toolkit but my `turnOffAll(state)` reducer causes thousands of rerenders (console log outputs) and an error about it in the browser.

I have [read](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers#resetting-and-replacing-state) that it's possible to `return` state, rather than "mutate" it from within `turnOffAll`.
So I've tried a variation of `turnOffAll` having: `return Array(screenSize.width * screenSize.height).fill(0)` but this causes an error in app.jsx that `dispatch(turnOffAll());` does not provide enough arguments.

Another approach I tried in `turnOffAll` is `state = initialState;` but while this doesn't cause unnececary rerenders, the state is not reset if I do a `console.log(useAppSelector((state) => state.pixels));` in app.jsx.

The relevant info from the files are below. This code is the situation in my first paragraph above and causes thousands of rerenders when calling `dispatch(turnOffAll());` from app.jsx:

pixelsSlice.ts:

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import type { RootState } from "./store";
import { Pixel, ScreenSize } from "./types";

//Defining a type for the slice state
interface PixelsState {
  pixels: Array<number>;
}

const screenSize = { width: 128, height: 59 };

//Define the initial state using the above type.
const initialState: PixelsState = {
  pixels: Array(screenSize.width * screenSize.height).fill(0),
};

export const pixelsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "pixels",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    turnOn(state, action: PayloadAction<Pixel>) {
      //This may look like mutating state, but Immer makes it ok:
      state.pixels[
        screenSize.width * action.payload.row + action.payload.column
      ] = 1;
    },
    turnOffAll(state) {
      state = initialState;
    },
  },
});

export const { turnOn, turnOffAll } = pixelsSlice.actions;

//Other code such as selectors can use the imported `RootState` type...
export const selectPixels = (state: RootState) => state.pixels;

export default pixelsSlice.reducer;
```

app.tsx:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useAppSelector, useAppDispatch } from "./app/hooks";
import { turnOn, turnOffAll } from "./app/pixelsSlice";
import type { Pixel } from "./app/types";

function App() {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  //Demonstrating reading and writing pixels from the redux store.
  console.log(useAppSelector((state) => state.pixels));

  let p: Pixel = { row: 1, column: 2 };
  dispatch(turnOn(p));
  console.log(useAppSelector((state) => state.pixels));

  dispatch(turnOffAll()); //THIS CAUSES THOUSANDS OF RERENDERS AND CONSOLE LOG OUTPUTS :(
  console.log(useAppSelector((state) => state.pixels));

  return <div className="App"></div>;
}

export default App;
```

hooks.ts:

```
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from "./store";

// Use throughout your app instead of plain `useDispatch` and `useSelector`
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

Comment: "thousands of rerenders" sounds like you are dispatching incorrectly. Can you please add the code where you dispatch, including all surrounding useEffect and at least an outline of the component?

Comment: @phry I've expanded the code from app.jsx where I do the dispatches. The other dispatch(turnOn) works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are breaking a very fundamental rule of React - not even Redux - here:

You trigger side effects during render.
React can trigger that render function any amount of times and not commit it to the DOM. It can be triggered because a parent component rerenders, because state changes, any number of reasons. One such reason might be that your Redux state changes.

So you dispatch, change state, trigger a rerender, dispatch again, which changes state (setting to another empty array - `[] !== []`) and triggers yet another render.

It is of utmost importance that your side effects like `dispatches` or state setter calls **always** happen in a `useEffect` or an event handler - and in the case of the `useEffect` that you also use a correct dependency array - hit the React documentation on that.

Also, your workflow of `dispatch` - `useSelector` - dispatch `useSelector` will probably not do what you want here. State reliably only changes between renders, not within a render.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @phry 's comment, the line `state =` in an Immer-powered reducer is always incorrect.  You need to either mutate a value *inside* of `state`, or return a new value.

If you want to replace the existing state, do `return initialState`.

See [the RTK usage guide page on "Writing Reducers with Immer"](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers#resetting-and-replacing-state) for more details.